# Django ORM: dynamic columns from reference model in resultset

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

Creating an app to track time off accrual.  Users have days and days have types like "Vacation" or "Sick"

Models:

DayType

- Name

UserDay

- Date
- DayType  (fk to DayType)
- Value    (+ for accrual, - for day taken)
- Note
- Total

I'm trying to generate the following resultset expanding the daytypes across columns.  Is this possible in the ORM, or do I have to build this in code?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd have an easier time by not putting the DayType in another model. Is there a specific reason you went that route?

If not, you should [take a look](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.choices) at the `choices` attribute of Django's `fields`. Your code would look something like this:

```
class UserDay(models.Model):
    DAY_TYPES = (
        ('vac', 'Vacation'),
        ('ill', 'Sick'),
    )
    day_type = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=DAY_TYPES)
    # Other fields here...
```

It seems like a somewhat cleaner solution since the types of days they have aren't likely to change very often. Plus, you can avoid a DB table and FK lookup by storing the values this way.